# OpenID 2 and openidselector Store in SQL

Tags: c#, openid, dotnetopenauth, openid-selector

I am implementing OpenID 2 (and/or OAuth 2) and also using the openidselector on my web application. What should I store in my SQL database so that I can match users up to my data when they login? For example, when a user logs in using Google, Twitter, OpenId or Facebook what key(s) should I store so that I can query other information out of my database? What should I use as a member id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique user information varies depending on which protocol you're using.  For OpenID (which Google also uses) the member id is found in the `IAuthenticationResponse.ClaimedIdentifier` property in DotNetOpenAuth.  For OAuth, which wasn't designed for authentication but is sometimes misused as such (Twitter and Facebook) there is no standard for a user identity, so you have to read their service docs to figure out what part of their OAuth responses include their member IDs and store that.

A user table that stores both OpenID Claimed Identifiers and various OAuth services' usernames can be tricky to get right.  Be careful.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response. I can keep the ClaimIdentifier and have the user add additional information.